# Find date (all languages)

Tags: c#, date, search

I hit the issue when I need to find first occurrence of date in a html source. This can be "January 24, 2000" as well as 24 Januar 2000 (slovak language) or any other language date format.

you may know a library that would be able to do this. I don't, google didn't help :(

I can't imagine how regex can do this as I would need to do a rule for all languages manually

Comment: Is this a web scraping application? Is it _your_ HTML source, or does it belong to someone else?

Comment: surely there is other information on the page that will tell you which language the page is in? Then you will only need to search for a specific string.

Comment: Good luck finding the first occurrence of (say) May 4th... does "05/04/2000" mean May 4th 2000, or April 5th 2000?

Comment: codesparkle No there is not  John: It's not mine, these are old records and we it's all different ^^   Jon Skeet: Jeez, good point :(

Answer (score 1):

The `CultureInfo` class is what you're looking for. Use `dt.ToString("D", c)` to pass the cultureinfo and get your format(btw, same as `dt.ToLongDateString`).

Have a look at the [**standard date and time format strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

You can use [`CultureInfo.GetCultures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx) to get all supported cultures.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2000, 1, 24);
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
string allTranslatedJanuaries = 
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cultures.Select(c =>
        String.Format("{0}: {1}", c.EnglishName, dt.ToString("D", c))));
```

Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/6ypqJE

On my server 352 cultures are installed, upon ideone only 112.